# splitting a subtitle text with re.split()

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I'm trying to split the following string

```
sub_text = """278
00:15:13,442 --> 00:15:14,436
Mr. Burns,

279
00:15:14,454 --> 00:15:17,893
I came here because my brother
is about to be wrongfully convicted,

280
00:15:17,947 --> 00:15:19,514
and the man I'm looking for

281
00:15:19,542 --> 00:15:21,010
would help me find the truth. 
"""
```

into a list that goes like this

`[('00:15:13,442 --> 00:15:14,436', 'Mr. Burns,'), ('00:15:14,454 --> 00:15:17,893', 'I came here because my brother is about to be wrongfully convicted,'), ...]`.

I'm trying to split the text with **regex** but it isn't working.

`re.split(r'^\d+$\n', sub_text)` returns an intact string even though everything seems to match just fine [here](https://regex101.com/r/mRGVyl/1).

Comment: The regex doesn't work because you're not using the multiline flag. But why not just do: `sub_text.split('\n\n')`?

Answer (score -1):

You could use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"(\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+ --> \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)\n(.+(?:\n.+)?)\n", sub_text)
[('00:15:13,442 --> 00:15:14,436', 'Mr. Burns,'), 
 ('00:15:14,454 --> 00:15:17,893', 'I came here because my brother\nis about to be wrongfully convicted,'), 
 ('00:15:17,947 --> 00:15:19,514', "and the man I'm looking for"), 
 ('00:15:19,542 --> 00:15:21,010', 'would help me find the truth. ')]
```